# Null when passing the context

Tags: java, android

In my dialog, I have a button that I can click on (class: `Dialog`). Once clicking on that button, the method `customTts()` (which is in `MainActivity` class) will be called:

```java
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
public void CustomTts(String input) throws Exception {
    Tts tts = new Tts(MainActivity.this, _mediaPlayer, barTop, barBottom);
    tts.say("Hello!");
}
```

The error that I get is:

> W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke
> virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources
> android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference

The first parameter of `Tts()` expects `Context`. So it seems like `MainActivity.this` returns *null*.

```java
public class Tts extends MainActivity {
    public Context context;
    private final MediaPlayer _mediaPlayer;
    private CopyBarVisualizer _barTop;
    private CopyBarVisualizer _barBottom;

    public Tts(Context context, MediaPlayer _mediaPlayer, BarVisualizer _barTop, BarVisualizer _barBottom) {
        this.context = context;
        this._mediaPlayer = _mediaPlayer;
        this._barTop = (CopyBarVisualizer) _barTop;
        this._barBottom = (CopyBarVisualizer) _barBottom;
    }

    @SuppressLint({"NewApi", "ResourceType", "UseCompatLoadingForColorStateLists"})
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    public void say(String text) throws Exception {
        InputStream stream = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.credential); // R.raw.credential is credential.json
        GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(stream);
        TextToSpeechSettings textToSpeechSettings =
                TextToSpeechSettings.newBuilder()
                        .setCredentialsProvider(
                                FixedCredentialsProvider.create(credentials)
                        ).build();
```

How can I pass the context in that case?

Comment: Can you include where you're calling this from and where the NPE occurred?

Comment: This is odd, but try to use `getApplicationContext()`

Comment: @Zain that seems like a workaround that ignores the real issue.

Comment: @HenryTwist yes .. we need to see more code

Comment: it doesn't make sense to click a button in your MainActivity and `MainActivity.this` return null. it seems that the issue is in the Tts class

Comment: I have updated my question so that you see what `Tts` needs `Context` for.

Comment: Obviously you need to use `Tts.this` instead of `MainActivity.this` as it is the name of the holding class

Comment: @Zain if I do this, I get the error _'Tts' is not an enclosing class_

Comment: So, you're calling `CustomTts()` from `MainActivity` class .. But you instantiate `Tts` class with `Tts tts = new Tts(MainActivity.this, _mediaPlayer, barTop, barBottom);` .. Activities not instantiated this way .. activities are system components that need to be instantiated by the system not the developer and that can be done with intents

Comment: Why 'Tts extends MainActivity'? Is that needed?

Comment: @hata no, not really. That was just for testing. So that can be deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I needed to do was to pass `getActivity()` for my Dialog class to `MainActivity()`. I was able to do this with an interface and `onAttach()`:

```java
public interface OnInputListener {
    void customTts(String input, Activity activity);
}
public OnInputListener onInputListener;

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    try {
        onInputListener = (OnInputListener) getActivity();
    }
    catch (ClassCastException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onAttach: ClassCastException: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

This is what I have used when the button was pressed:

```java
onInputListener.customTts(input, getActivity());
```

And in my MainActivity class, I have changed my `customTts()` method to this:

```java
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
@Override
public void customTts(String input, Activity activity) {
    Tts tts = new Tts(activity, _mediaPlayer, barTop, barBottom);
    try {
        tts.say(input);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```